# Is there a less arbitrary way define the margin in non-inferiority and/or equivalence trials?

Tags: statistical-significance, equivalence, non-inferiority

In a typical equivalence trial, the researcher defines some threshold below which the difference between two means is not considered practically meaningful. In a non-inferiority trial, the same kind of margin is used test the hypothesis that one thing is "equal to or better than" another.

In reality though the researcher is testing the alternative hypothesis that the above the non-inferiority margin (or between the margins for equivalence), and that margin could be defined in an extremely permissive manner. The small body of literature on margin select is mostly focused on how inconsistent and problematic margin selection is in existing research.

This leads me to a few questions:

1. How does one safeguard against overly permissive non-inferiority or equivalence margins? I realize that this is probably as arbitrary of a things a defining what level of p-value is significant, or what effect size is small/medium/large. Still, is there a way to quantify how well the chosen margin insures that one quantity is close to being "non-inferior" or "equivalent" to another?
2. When practical significance is hard to define, how do you go about choosing a sensible margin?
3. What if practical significance is on a spectrum rather than binary? What if you want to test how close to zero the difference between two means are, rather than if they pass a predefined threshold?
4. Do do the definitions of "false positive" and "incorrect rejection" need to be reformulated with NI and equivalence hypotheses? In an equivalence trial you're hypothesizing that the mean difference is zero, but inappropriate margins could make it easy to incorrectly conclude "equivalence".

I have a feeling that the answer to this is that "it's simply arbitrary", but it's worth a shot in the dark.